# How to enable RSS auto discovery in firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser, rss

Firefox used to have a rss icon inside the url box.

Now I can only find it as a button I can add to the toolbar, which is too big for something that will be disabled most of the time.

Is there a way to make it work as before? I want it to appear only when the current website has an RSS Feed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try one of these extensions:

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/rss-icon-in-awesombar/
- <strike>https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/rss-icon/</strike>

The first one uses the old Firefox 3 icon, the second one uses a new style, which fits better to the new look since Firefox 4, but is buggy.

Comment: The second one was buggy. The first one did the trick.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Thought that I had tried them both. But thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for an add-on. Simply use the customization function for the toolbar - the icon is still there.

Comment: Can you add a link to a screen shot showing where the icon is.

Comment: Adding more detail would vastly improve this answer.

Comment: The OP has already stated that "Now I can only find it as a button I can add to the toolbar, which is too big for something that will be disabled most of the time." Please read the question carefully before replying.